# Sublime Text 3: How to configure rubocop.yml path in sublime settings?

Tags: ruby, sublimetext3

I have installed [rubocop package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/RuboCop) for sublime text 3. I am trying to set custom rubocop configuration by providing rubocop.yml path to Rubocop.sublime-settings. Please find my configuration-snippet

```
  "rubocop_config_file":  "./.rubocop.yml"
```

However  rubocop does not work when I give this configuration. It only works for

```
  "rubocop_config_file":  ""
```

How can i fix this and provide the path of my rubocop.yml to rubocop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some prodding, I found this :

> By default, the linter plugin looks for a config file called
>   .rubocop.yml in the current directory and its parents
>   - https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-rubocop

Even though I am not using the linter-plugin, I figured rubocop does the same. So by placing the .rubocop.yml in the current directory or any of its parents, I was able to get my .rubcop.yml file to be picked by rubocop. On a side note, I did not update configuration of the rubocop package, it automatically picks the .rubocop.yml.

Answer (score 1):

Other settings in this Rubocop.sublime-settings seem to use a complete path.

So instead of using the dot to start at the folder where the Rubocop.sublime-settings file is located use a full path like the examples for other Rubocop.sublime-settings configurations.

Hope this helps